# Get current user's info from Twitter API V2

Tags: twitter

On version 1.1 of the Twitter API, we could use "account/verify_credentials".

However this now requires Elevated access to use the 1.1 version of the API.

Is there a way todo it using the V2 part of the Twitter API?

Edit: all I need is the username

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there is not a way to do this in v2. However, a future API feature *may* add this (probably as part of the OAuth 2.0 user implementation that is [currently being worked on](https://twittercommunity.com/t/announcing-oauth-2-0-beta/159189)).

You can request elevated access to get to v1.1 endpoints for free.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done through the [`GET /2/users/me`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users-me) API call, but that requires both the [`tweet.read`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/authorization-code) and `users.read` scopes.  This has the side effect of letting the app read tweets from any protected accounts you follow (and perhaps subscriber-only tweets).

Ideally, Twitter would just implement OpenID Connect, but it currently does not.  With that, you'd get an `id_token` in addition to the `access_token` and `refresh_token`.  The `id_token` would identify which account was being used.